# module_invoke: using with a view and display as a block Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, view

ok, this works great for regular blocks:

```
     <?php $block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', '15');
   print $block['content']; ?>
```

but I have a display for a view that is a block and hovering over the edit in the admin/blocks page, I get:

/views/sc_file_view-block_4

So the first thing I tried was:

```
                <?php $block = module_invoke('views','view','block', 'sc_file_view_4');
           print $block['content']; ?>
```

But no output. Is there another way to pull a block (that is actually a display view as block?)

I've tried changing view/block and such but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get block content by `views_get_view_result` function.

Check for more info: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it worked in my case just now as

```
print render($block['content']);
```